# UWP CloudBlob.DownloadFileAsync Access Denied error

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I'm writing a simple UWP app where a user sends InkCanvas stroke information to an Azure blockBlob, and then retrieves some different InkCanvas stroke container info to render to the canvas.

I save the .ink file to the applicationData local folder with StrokeContainer.saveAsync() to the same location and same file name (it gets replaced with each transaction), and then upload it with CloudBlockBlob.uploadAsync().

My problem arises when trying to download a file from my Azure server - I get an "Access Denied" error.

```
 async private void loadInkCanvas(string name)
    {
        //load ink canvas
        //add strokes to the end of the name
        storageInfo.blockBlob = storageInfo.container.GetBlockBlobReference(name + "_strokes"); 
        //check to see if the strokes file exists
        if (await storageInfo.blockBlob.ExistsAsync){
            //then the stroke exists, we can load it in.
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("ink.ink", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var outputStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await storageInfo.blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(storageFile);//gives me the "Access Denied" error here

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, all I've found online is that you shouldn't put the direct path into the target location, but rather use ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder .

Comment: Do take a look here: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20120419-ClosingStreamsInWinRt.html. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DownloadToFileAsync` method does help you read the file stream from azure storage to local file, you don't need to open local file for reading by yourself. In your code, you opened the file stream and make the file occupied and then invoked the `DownloadToFileAsync` method to try to access the occupied file which lead 'Access Denied' exception.

The solution is easy, just download to the local file without open, code as follows:

```
if (await blockBlob.ExistsAsync())
{
   //then the stroke exists, we can load it in.
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("ink.ink", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(storageFile);    
}
```

If you want to read the file stream by yourself, you need to use the `DownloadToStreamAsync` method instead of `DownloadToFileAsync` like follows:

```
if (await blockBlob.ExistsAsync())
{       
   StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("ink.ink", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
   //await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(storageFile);
   using (var outputStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
   {
       await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(outputStream.AsStreamForWrite());    
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I found that that was my issue, I must have mindlessly wrote that in there and missed the most obvious solution.